# how to connect ledstrip to arduino

Tags: arduino, led

On Adafruit there was an example on how to connect a ledstrip to an arduino, but it said "For longer strips requiring more than 1A, wire power directly to the strip, then run power and ground wires back to the Arduino." I didn't fully understand it so i made a sketch on circuits.io . Since there isn't a normal ledstrip in there i used a RGB to show my sketch, but i can't test it. So before i fry my arduino or ledstrip can someone explain if this is correct or if it needs to be changed? Also can i connect everything on a breadboard or not, since the higher voltage and amp.
https://i.gyazo.com/27e9a6527805b6e4e898a8f32f66de61.png

Comment: so the LED strip has its own batteries? therefore the arduino it's not powering it correct? can you use a relay instead?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about hardware, not programming.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That would work.

I believe this is the same as this https://learn.adafruit.com/rgb-led-strips/usage

about the breadboard it really depends on the breadboard they can vary from cheap ones 0.5A to 2A is usually the maximum current rating for a good solderless breadboard

Comment: So if i hook up everything to the breadboard except the power of the ledstrip from the external power suply nothing will go wrong?

Comment: Correct. specially if you don't connect any power to go to the ledstrip, as the leds wont turn on. you would then have to do something like in the adafruit example and connect the power from the Arduino although it probably wont  give enough current you might get a dim light.

My suggestion is to do what you where going to do originally, dont worry about the breadboard current rating, the worst that could happend with thoose current rating is get some over heating on the breadboard if the circuit is asembled correctly. no harm will come to the arduino. if it works build on a stripboard.

Comment: here you got what you are trying to do with an arduino due http://i39.tinypic.com/igixaa.jpg

Comment: One more question, i have a dc charger, do i need to strip it for the positive and negative or is there another way?

Comment: you got several options: msx-elektronika.pl/pl/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/prdc1.jpg or http://uk.farnell.com/productimages/standard/en_GB/2381876-40.jpg or even: media.nkcelectronics.com/img/bbps06.jpg - The most "hackery" way would be to open the charge unsolder/cut the cable and connect a new one...

Answer (score -1):

Here are what you need:

Your Arduino.

An external power supply. Get something like [this](https://kutop.com/120w-5v-12v-24v-constant-voltage-regulated-switching-power-supply.html?___store=default&___store=default&gclid=CjwKEAiAjIbBBRCitNvJ1o257WESJADpoUt0UsTaK__iUP9BJa3y4CvITH-2Fi0L0zc9i9FUIQpL5xoCaq_w_wcB) for your external power suply.

You led strip.

---

Connect:

PWM pulse of Arduino -> Data IN of led strip

All GND togheters

5V output of external power supply-> VCC of led strip

Computer -> USB -> Arduino

---

External power supplies give you high current levels, perfect for many leds. Dont worry about your breadboard melting, it should be able to handle it.

Comment: He has regular RGB strips not addressable ones.

Comment: Put a relay between VCC and external power supply. Let the Arduino control the relay.